# Develop an app exclusively for iphone and not for ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am developing an app exclusively for iphone and I have set the deployment device as iPhone in my Deployment Info. Yet, it is rejected at application review with the following message `iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution`
What can I do here?

Comment: You can let it run on an iPad?

Comment: All iPhone-only apps must run as-is on an iPad.

Comment: no, i cant do that at this point

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do. Rules are rules.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to let it run on the iPad. The guidelines make it so all iPhone apps have to run on the iPad (at minimum as a blown up iPone app). If it doesn't look good yet, that's fine, most apps that do that don't look that great anyways. Its just providing the usage of the app for the iPad users as well and literally takes no more than 3 minutes to check the box to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Launch Screen File in XCode 6 or later and use the Launch image. Also have a look at the following SO links which have the same query as yours()if you havent gone through them till now)

[Make an iPhone specific app work on iPad to meet Apple requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527781/make-an-iphone-specific-app-work-on-ipad-to-meet-apple-requirements)

[2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540357/2-10-iphone-apps-must-also-run-on-ipad-without-modification-at-iphone-resolutio)

[App Rejection due to the launch screen](http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2j41tj/app_rejection/)