# iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

[image: I have used These launch images]

My app is again rejected by app store. The reason is "iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution" . I have checked my app in iPad and it works fine. Here is the screenshot [app on iPad](http://share.pho.to/9nq2T) Please tell me what to do. My app is only for iPhone. Here is the screenshots of my app settings [image]

Please help me out.

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527781/make-an-iphone-specific-app-work-on-ipad-to-meet-apple-requirements , 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540357/2-10-iphone-apps-must-also-run-on-ipad-without-modification-at-iphone-resolutio

Comment: @Venkat There is no launch screen in my project. I have used LaunchImage in Image xcassetes.

Comment: Had you put the splash screen for the iPad..? I guess may be its aproblem

Comment: @Venkat is there any issue If I used universal for image assets.

Comment: Did you test you app in iPad ? even if its iPhone app, we can run it in iPad also.. I think apple tried to test your app in iPad.. So you check that first.

Comment: @SunnyShah no I didn't used any iPad image

Comment: @SunnyShah Is there any issue If I used image assets in Universal

Comment: @Venkat Yes I have test my app in iPad also.Its  working fine.

Comment: can you show me the screenshot of launch screen images added in asset?

Comment: Strange.... Better you contact apple dev support team to know what exactly the error is and get help from them to fix the issue.

Comment: @SudhaTiwari I m not sure but It may be..  you should ask app dev support as Venkat said. and check app in all device (Old not retina and retina). it must show the 2x button in all.

Comment: @SunnyShah Yes, I have checked app in iPad. Here is the screenshots. http://share.pho.to/9nq2T

Comment: @SudhaTiwari Screenshot is correct. just make sure for all iPad simulator

Comment: @SunnyShah 
 
I have checked my app in 3.5, ipad mini, ipad2 and ipad retina. App is working fine. launch screen is also available there. But I want to know in iPad retina there are 1X and 2X button but in iPad mini and iPad 2 this button is not available. why?

Comment: @Venkat 
 
I have checked my app in 3.5, ipad mini, ipad2 and ipad retina. App is working fine. launch screen is also available there. But I want to know in iPad retina there are 1X and 2X button but in iPad mini and iPad 2 this button is not available. why?

Comment: Can i see your LaunchImage.xcassest..?

Comment: @SunnyShah I have shared screenshot in question

Comment: @SunnyShah check my updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93664/discussion-between-sunny-shah-and-sudha-tiwari).

Comment: @SudhaTiwari go to app dev support ask them

Comment: @SudhaTiwari: Go through all screens in iPad, check the UI, also it would be nice if you can check that you are not using any feature which is an "iPhone-only" feature (may be hardware requirement) and causing crash or any issue on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all the functionalities are working fine on iPad. Check all the screens, keyboard should not hide the text fields and options anywhere. You can check in 3.5 inch simulator and check Default(Splash) image shows on iPad or not.

Comment: I have checked my app in 3.5, ipad mini, ipad2 and ipad retina. App is working fine. launch screen is also available there. But I want to know in iPad retina there are 1X and 2X button but in iPad mini and iPad 2 this button is not available. why?

Comment: Does apple give any comments for rejection? Post that also. One time i faced the same case for login button is out of the screen.