# Odd padding in iPad Cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

Can anyone explain this odd padding that exists outside the entire webview?

Our app has been denied by Apple because of this issue.

I have Googled it for days with no success.

[image]

Comment: That looks to me like an iPhone app running on an iPad. Do you support the iPad?

Comment: It is. We have disabled iPad, but here's from Apple: We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.3, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines. Please revise your app to ensure it runs at iPhone resolution on iPad.

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527781/make-an-iphone-specific-app-work-on-ipad-to-meet-apple-requirements

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this in your config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
</platform>
```

Universal is the default value, so make sure you are not setting target-device to something else ;)